# Requesting other application data

Tags: android, shared, broadcast

What would be good approach to establish communication between different APKs? One app can send request to other apps and wait for response.

I can think of:
1. using BroadCast receivers: send "request" broadcast and receive returned broadcasts (results). This seems nice clean solution, no security problems, but how to get all results back as "one" - usually I will want to send out broadcast to collect app identifications, and get result like array.


2. use sharedUserId between all these apps and gather or execute whatever I need directly on the apps. But here are have couple of more loose ends:
  - how do I get list of apps (through list of installed packages?)
- is with sharedUserId and same signature possible to access other app internals? like register/unregister component, etc.?

Thanks!

## EDIT:

Have been reading more about ordered broadcasts and so far this seems good way to go. Using order broadcast each of other apps will fill in its own data part and result will be returned back to supplied "final" receiver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using ordered broadcasts. When broadcast is send out, each receiver adds its information and last receiver calls resultReceiver.